# Trying to get flexbox items to have more height than flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

So my flex container of height:100px has three flex items inside, I set the height of these items to 300px(I want them to be 200px bigger than the flex container) so that they overflow the container titem, however the flex container grows along with the flex items instead, how can I achieve this?

```html
<section style="width:100%; height:100px; padding:0px 75px; margin-top:200px; outline:1px solid red; display:flex; align-items:flex-end; justify-content:space-around; overflow:visible;">
    <div style="width:28%; height:300px; outline:1px solid red;">
 
 </div>
 <div style="width:28%; height:300px; outline:1px solid red;">
 
 </div>
 <div style="width:28%; height:300px; outline:1px solid red;">
 
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The container does keep its height, though the items gets pushed upwards as the `align-items` is set to `flex-end`, which mean they are bottom aligned. So what's the actual goal here? ... And note, any elements positioned after the container in the markup will be overlapped by these items

Answer (score 0):

You should probably change the vertical alignment (`align-items`) and also consider `box-sizing:border-box` so that the padding doesn't increase the width more than 100%.

```html
<section style="width:100%; height:100px; padding:0px 75px;box-sizing:border-box; outline:1px solid red; display:flex; align-items:flex-start; justify-content:space-around; overflow:visible;">
  <div style="width:28%; height:300px; outline:1px solid green;">

  </div>
  <div style="width:28%; height:300px; outline:1px solid green;">

  </div>
  <div style="width:28%; height:300px; outline:1px solid green;">

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want to achieve but having the grren divs overflowing part going up instead of down

Comment: @PeterDickngale this what you had no? can then explain what is the exact issue with your actual code? ...